# HTML unit LOGIN

Tags: java, htmlunit

Basically I'm trying to use HTML unit to perform a login.

However the login as form to input the username with a button next, then it actulizes the form and the password should be inputed. My problem occurs when I do `button.click()` the page gets the first form not the second where should be inputted the password

```
public void search() throws Exception {
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();

    HtmlPage p = wb.getPage(
            "https://account.booking.com/sign-in?op_token=EgVvYXV0aCJHChQ2Wjcyb0hPZDM2Tm43emszcGlyaBIJYXV0aG9yaXplGhpodHRwczovL2FkbWluLmJvb2tpbmcuY29tLyoCe31CBGNvZGUqDDCgqZHe5rMjOgBCAA");
    // HtmlPage p = (HtmlPage) wb.getPage(this.bUrl);

    List<HtmlForm> form = p.getForms();

    form.get(0).getInputByName("loginname").setValueAttribute("1234567");
    HtmlForm fm = form.get(0);
    System.out.println(form.get(0).getInputByName("loginname").getValueAttribute().toString());

    List<Object> button = fm.getByXPath("//button[@type='submit']");

    HtmlButton bt = (HtmlButton) button.get(0);

    System.out.println(p.asText() + "\n+_________________");
    bt.click();
    System.out.println(p.asText());

}
```

The output shows to be the same before and after the `bt.click()`

```
1234567
Booking.com Account
This website uses cookies. Click here for more information.
Close
Sign In to Manage Your Property
Username
1234567
Next
Having trouble signing in?
Questions about your property or the Extranet? Visit the Partner Help Center or ask another partner on the Partner Forum.
Add your property to Booking.com
Create a partner account to list and manage your property.
Register
By clicking "Allow access" you authorize Extranet to use your Booking.com account info according to Extranet Terms of service.
+_________________
Booking.com Account
This website uses cookies. Click here for more information.
Close
Sign In to Manage Your Property
Username
Enter your username
Next
Having trouble signing in?
Questions about your property or the Extranet? Visit the Partner Help Center or ask another partner on the Partner Forum.
Add your property to Booking.com
Create a partner account to list and manage your property.
Register
By clicking "Allow access" you authorize Extranet to use your Booking.com account info according to Extranet Terms of service.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your code is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of Html and HtmlUnit.

```
HtmlPage p = wb.getPage(.....
```

retrieves a (html) page. This page is shown inside a browser window (same in HtmlUnit). If you interact with elements on this page like

```
form.get(0).getInputByName("loginname").setValueAttribute("1234567");
```

or better

```
form.get(0).getInputByName("loginname").type("1234567");
```

these elements are changing there state and as a result the whole page changes.
But:
Clicking an submit button is a total different story. In this case the browser (and HtmlUnit also) sends a Http Request to the server and gets back a new HtmlPage. Usually this page is shown inside the same window.

In HtmlUnit this is reflected by the return value of the click method - the return value is the new page. As long you are not assigning this value to a page variable and doing your next steps on this new page you are still working with the old one.

BTW: there is a commented sample on the [Getting Started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) HtmlUnit page.

So far the simplest version of form/submit handling. But today the thinks are a bit (in fact many bits) more complicated because most of the pages out there doing (additional) magic based on javascript (e.g. Ajax).

Suggestion:
if you send me some credentials via private mail i can try to help you to get this login working based on HtmlUnit.

Suggestion 2:
Try to learn and understand all the technical stuff related to the web, without this you will be lost.

Comment: Firstly, let me thank you for your response.

To be frank I've tried before to save the return of method click() on a new HTML page, but the output was the same. Most probably is due to the javascript magic that you reffered.
How can I get your email adress ?

Comment: Regarding the email you can look at the htmlunit hompage, there is a list of contributors....